# How do I edit an element from an index page if they are nested in another resource in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I need to edit the **card** element from the **card index page**, on this page I have only one parameter - the card ID. The decrease in the number of parameters was due to rewriting the route for the index page only.
I am new to Ruby and do not quite understand how I can find these parameter(board_id, column_id). Controllers with the function of updating the card are already there. How do I find these options correctly?

I have this routes:

```rb
get 'cards' => 'cards#index', as: :cards

resources :boards do
  resources :columns, except: [:index, :show, :edit] do 
    resources :cards, except: [:index, :show]
    end
  end
end
```

So to edit the card element I need :board_id, :column_id, cards/:id:

```rb
board_column_card_path  PATCH   /boards/:board_id/columns/:column_id/cards/:id(.:format) cards#update
```

My cards_controller:

```rb
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  def new; end

  def index
    @cards = Card.all.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end


  def create
    @card = @column.cards.build(card_params)
    @card.user = current_user

    if @card.save
      flash[:success] = "Card was successfully created."
    else
      flash[:error] = @card.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end

  def update
    if @card.update(card_params)
      flash[:success] = "Card was successfully updated."
    else
      flash[:error] = @card.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should never really need to nest the resource more then one level deep. http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

Comment: I completely agree with @max: you need to utilise shallow nesting otherwise you will likely create a massive headache for yourself: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I thought about it, but unfortunately I can’t change these routes, a lot of logic in the controllers and views will need to be rewritten for which I am not responsible.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to update your card, with just your card id? This can be done easily by changing your routes. I recommned using shallow nesting: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting.

```
# inside your routes.rb file - you can add exceptions 
# as in the code you have posted above if you wish
 resources :boards do
    resources :columns, shallow: true do      
      resources :cards, shallow: true do        
      end
    end
  end

  # now because you are using shallow editing you can simply do this:
edit_card_path(@card.id)
```

And when you want to update, you can do so easily by just using the card_id. You will not need your the board and column ids. It is hard to be more specific because you have not given the card_params nor any forms.